# BHO render event

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, bho

I am developing IE extensions using BHO. Currently I am using OnDocumentComplete event which fires when the page loading is completed. I want to inject my JavaScript while rendering HTML such that I can update HTML on the fly.

Simple example:
I want to replace HREF attribute. But on OnDocumentComplete event user can click the link and can access the actual link. But if he/she waits till the page load complete then he/she will be redirected to the updated link.

Please provide your valuable inputs such that DOM can be updated while rendering.

Thanks,
Maitrey

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem, have you find a solution to inject JS before the document is marked as complete?

Answer (score 0):

While page is loading you can use:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function(){
      /* DOM handling */ 
   }
</script>
```

to execute Javascript, is this what you meant?

Comment: But how to inject JavaScript using BHO event?

Answer (score 0):

you can execute your javascript using `IHTMLWindow2::execScript` called on the window object inside the `OnDocumentComplete` handler:

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
  HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
  IHTMLWindow2 parentWindow = document.parentWindow;
  parentWindow.execScript("alert('your javascript')");
}
```

where `webBrowser` is the object of the `WebBrowser` class that you've set in `SetSite`